# Reference Masterpage from BasePage

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a Masterpage with some public properties which I **SET** from the content page, however I now have a Basepage which holds the common functionality. Question, when I move the Master.MasterDBCode into the basePage but I cannot seem to reference the 'MasterDBCode' on the MasterPage like I did when it was directly connected to the content page...

---

### **Code that worked**

**In Masterpage**

```
public string MasterDBCode
{
   get { return mDBCode; }
   set { mDBCode = value; }
}
```

**In content page**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/SomeFolder.Master" 
 AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="somepage.aspx.cs" Inherits="SomeNamespace" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/SomeFolder.Master" %>

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    ...//other code

    Master.MasterDBCode = mDBCode;

    ...//more code
 }
```

----------Non working Code -------------

```
 public partial class basePage:System.Web.UI.Page
 protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
 {
    ...//other code

    Master.MasterDBCode = mDBCode;  

    ...//other code
 }
```

----------End of non working code ---------

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Hence I deleted the post

Comment: Your base page cannot access master page properties unless its a content page.

Comment: thanks, but how do I change basepage to content page. My basepage is simply a class file not aspx page.

Comment: Not sure why you need then this class to inherit from "Page" if its not going to be aspx. You can create a common utility class. To call utility class you will have to pass the value of master page properties from the calling content page.